# Extract URL in JSON String with Python using re.match() or split()

Tags: python, json, url

With my Python Code I extract a special part of a JSON File (a list in a list or part of a dictionary):

```
import json
import urllib

f = open('json-test-file-for-insta-url-snippet.json')
data = json.load(f)

print(json.dumps(data["event"]["attachments"][0]["text"]))
```

I got this Result:

```
"\u201cUNLIMITED LIVE\u201d world tour moved to 2021!\nDue to the Covid-19 pandemic and the subsequent regulations and concert restrictions, the world tour, originally planned for the autumn of 2020, could not take place. \n\"\u201eI was very much looking forward to our tour in autumn 2020 all over the world, so I\u2019m deeply sorry that these concerts had to be rescheduled due to the Covid-19 pandemic. I\u2019m very happy that we have already found new dates for our tour in autumn 2021, because I cannot wait to return to get back on stage and to play for you guys. Take care of yourselves \u2013 I hope to see you all happy and healthy again very, very soon!\u201d \nAll your tickets remain valid for the new dates! Please find them below: \n\nKAZ Almaty - Sep 11, 2021\nRUS Yekaterinburg - Sep 14, 2021\nRUS Kazan, Sep 16, 2021\nRUS Voronezh - Sep 18, 2021\nRUS Krasnodar - Sep 20, 2021\nRUS Moscow - Sep 22, 2021\nRUS St. Petersburg - Sep 24, 2021\nUKR Kharkiv - Sep 26 2021\nUKR Odessa - Sep 28, 2021\nUKR Kiev - Sep 30, 2021\nITA Bolzano - Oct 13, 2021\nITA Bologna - Oct 15, 2021\nITA Genoa - Oct 16, 2021\nITA Milano - Oct 17, 2021\nITA Conegliano Veneto - Oct 19, 2021\nBG Sofia - Oct 24, 2021\nRO Bucharest - Oct 26, 2021\nRO Cluj - Oct 29, 2021  #davidgarrett #tour2021 #unlimited #live #postponed\n*Score* -2.57x | *Likes* 338 (-830) | *Comments* 13 (-46)\n_Posted on Tuesday, August 18 at 9:59 AM CEST <https://www.instagram.com/p/CEBew-xHwhJ/|(Instagram)>_\n_Received via Viral Alert_"
```

Now I want to extract the Insta-URL in the end - how can I do it in Python? Is it only possible with Regex or is there a smarter way? I read a lot in Stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex to extract the Instagram link from your text:

```
<(.+)\|\(Instagram\)>
```

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/WpL2dw/1)

It searches for any text wrapped by `<`and `|(Instagram)>` and stores it in a capturing group.

---

You can use it like this

```py
import re

INSTA_LINK_RE = re.compile(r'<(.+)\|\(Instagram\)>')

match = INSTA_LINK_RE.search(json.dumps(data["event"]["attachments"][0]["text"]))

if match:
    url = match[1]  # gets the first capturing group
```

---

I you want to get only the shortcode, use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/WpL2dw/2)

```
<https://www.instagram.com/p/(.+)/\|\(Instagram\)>
```

---

This works if you have a `str` object to analyse with your `str` regex.

If your text is a `bytes` object, you need to decode it first...

```py
# JSON files are normally encoded with UTF-8
json.dumps(data["event"]["attachments"][0]["text"]).decode('utf8`)
```

... or use a `bytes` regex

```py
# note the `b` prefix for the regex pattern
INSTA_LINK_RE = re.compile(br'<(.+)\|\(Instagram\)>')
```

---

To directly get a dict which contain `str` objects you could also pass the encoding to the `open` function:

```py
f = open('json-test-file-for-insta-url-snippet.json', encoding='utf-8`)
```

---

See some python docs to learn more:

- [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes#bytes.decode)
- [open](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)
- [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: thx to all, it helped me a lot! it works fine for my nutshell experiment, when I give the string directly with data = stringxyz - but when I try to get the shortcode result from my local json file, I got Error:

Comment: `import re
import json

f = open('json-test-file-for-insta-url-snippet.json')
data = json.load(f)

print(json.dumps(data["event"]["attachments"][0]["text"]))

print(re.findall("<https://www.instagram.com/p/(.+)/\|\(Instagram\)>", data))`

Output:

`File "get-text-from-attachements.py", line 47, in <module>
    print(re.findall("<https://www.instagram.com/p/(.+)/\|\(Instagram\)>", data))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 239, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

what are I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since your read the text from a file, you get a `bytes` object instead of a `str` one. You have to decode the bytes to get a proper string. JSON files are encoded in UTF8, so you have to use `data.decode('uft8')`. also see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes#bytes.decode

Comment: ok thx, I tried

`print(re.findall("<https://www.instagram.com/p/(.+)/\|\(Instagram\)>", data.decode('utf8')))`

and I got:

`File "get-text-from-attachements.py", line 47, in <module>
    print(re.findall("<https://www.instagram.com/p/(.+)/\|\(Instagram\)>", data.decode('utf8')))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'`

is there a special decode-task for dictionaries?

Comment: encoding concerns text data. your `data`variables actually is a dict since it contains your parsed JSON. please look at the updated answer and the links at the bottom of it

Comment: thx a lot, seems like I have to handle the basics first. When I try the bytes regex, I got `AttributeError: 're.Pattern' object has no attribute 'find'` - so a byte data is different from dict data? I am sorry, I am very new to Python. and thx for the links!

Comment: @Chrissi this time it is an mistake in my answer. you should use `search`, not `find`. The answer is updated. The bytes is the text data read from the file, but once it is parsed by the `json.load` method, it comes in the form of a dict containing your JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is in a string format. Regex is the smartest way (Takes time to learn but its a very strong tool). However, you can use a module called [instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/). Not sure what you're working with, but instaloader is really helpful with Instagram.

Comment: thx a lot, I will check it out, but I just need the URL (or the Shortcode) from that JSON String. I tried it with Regex like 'print(re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", data))' but I got 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

link = json.dumps(data["event"]["attachments"][0]["text"])
link_list = ','.split(link)
for x in link_list:
    x = x[19:]
    if x.stratswith('https:'):
        i = '|'.split(x)
        link = i[0]
```

First I split the data in a list then I browse the list till I find something starting with https:(the link).I then split it once again at the end of the link and extract it from the list